# Javascript InvalidStateError in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, safari

A webpage which I developed is giving issues in Safari browser. Its running fine on chrome and firefox.
Currently, I am getting the error `InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.`
at the line
`document.getElementById("var_time_start").valueAsDate = pastDate;`

From my understanding , this seems to be some sync issue between the HTML code and JS code. But I am not sure how to fix it.
Also, the HTML code is run as a PHP file.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineGraph);
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);

document.getElementById("chart_div_title").innerHTML = "Time Series selected :" + variable + " " + height + " at " + station;

//gets the current dateTime and dateTime-1 day for Default first API call 
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var end_dateTime = date + '+' + time;
var pastDate = new Date(today);
pastDate.setDate(pastDate.getDate() - 1);
date = pastDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (pastDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pastDate.getDate();
time = pastDate.getHours() + ":" + pastDate.getMinutes() + ":" + pastDate.getSeconds();
start_dateTime = date + '+' + time;

//Initialises the datepicker value on screen as per the first API call
document.getElementById("var_time_start").valueAsDate = pastDate;
document.getElementById("var_time_end").valueAsDate = today;

//Listener to catch any changes in the Datepicker values
var form = document.getElementById("date_block");
form.addEventListener('change', function() {
    pd = document.getElementById("var_time_start").value;
    td = document.getElementById("var_time_end").value;
    start_dateTime = pd
    end_dateTime = td
    //console.log('pd=', pd, 'td=', td)
    $("#var_period").selectpicker('val', 'Custom');
    get_api_call()
});
var form2 = document.getElementById("date_block2");
form2.addEventListener('change', function() {
    pd = document.getElementById("var_time_start").value;
    td = document.getElementById("var_time_end").value;
    start_dateTime = pd
    end_dateTime = td
    //console.log('pd=', pd, 'td=', td)
    $("#var_period").selectpicker('val', 'Custom');
    get_api_call()
});
```

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="chart_div_title">
            <h3></h3>
        </div>


    <div class="col-lg-12" >
        <hr />
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group" >
        <label for="var_agg">Aggregation:</label>
                <br/>

                
                    <select  id="var_agg" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" >
                </select>                
        </div >
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label for="var_processing">Processing Level:</label>
                <br/>

                
                    <select  id="var_processing" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" >
                </select>                
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group" >
        <label for="var_resolution">Resolution:</label>
        <br/>
                
                    <select  id="var_resolution" class="selectpicker">
                    <option value="min" >Minute</option>
                    <option value="hr" selected="selected">Hourly</option>
                    <option value="day" >Daily</option>            
                </select>                
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label for="var_period">Period:</label>
                <br/>
                
                    <select  id="var_period" class="selectpicker">
                    <option value="24Hours" selected="selected">Last 24 Hours</option>
                    <option value="Week" >Last Week</option>
                    <option value="Month" >Last Month</option>
                    <option value="Year" >Last Year</option>
                    <option value="All" >All data</option>
                    <option value="Custom" >Custom</option>                
                </select>                
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group" id ='date_block'>
        <label for="var_time_start">From:</label>
            <br/>
            <input id="var_time_start" type="date" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group" id ='date_block2'>
        <label for="var_time_end">To:</label>
        <br/>
        <input id="var_time_end" type="date">
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-12" >
        <div id="curve_chart" class="chart"></div>
    </div>

  <script src="js/show_graph.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stable Safari still doesn't support input[type=date], and unfortunately, they broke the internet once again by exposing future APIs for things they don't yet support, which prevents us web-authors to correctly feature-detect.

Comment: @Kaiido So, is there any workaround for this? An other ways to apply a datepicker in safari

Comment: Seems like a workaround is to drop the time portion: https://upokary.com/invalidstateerror-the-object-is-in-an-invalid-state-in-safari. I ran into this when using datetime-local input so not an option for me, I will split the UI into two inputs instead.